# border color of uisegmentedcontrol

Tags: ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

I am having trouble changing the border color of my segmented control in iOS7.   I found the follow suggestions elsewhere on stackoverflow:

```
    [[UISegmentedControl appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                                             UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                                                             UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0],
                                                             UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:0.0],
                                                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor],

                                                             } forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [self.segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                                    UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
                                                    UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0],
                                                    UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:0.0],
                                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor],

                                                    } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But in both cases, my border is still a blue color.  I can't seem to change the font shadow, the border color or anything else via the settitleTextAttributes.

How do i adjust the border color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I struggled way too much with this.  So I did a work around.  i ended up just creating a new UILabel and add it as subview to each of the items in the segmented controller.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
    NSArray * segments = @[@"Crop",@"Nutrient",@"Product Group"];

    [self.segmentedControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-yellowgradient.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [self.segmentedControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
    for (int i=0; i<[self.segmentedControl.subviews count]; i++)
    {

        [[self.segmentedControl.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        l.text = [segments objectAtIndex:i];
        l.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        l.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        l.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
        l.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];


        CGRect  f = [[self.segmentedControl.subviews objectAtIndex:0] frame];
        f.size.width = self.segmentedControl.frame.size.width/3;
        f.size.height = self.segmentedControl.frame.size.height;
        f.origin.x = 0;
        f.origin.y = 0;

        l.frame = f;

        [[[self.segmentedControl subviews] objectAtIndex:i] addSubview:l];

    }
}
else{
    // if it's not IOS7, then do what i was doing before for ios6.1 and below
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[segmentControlObj setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```